# Prestashop - Combination: Impact on Price as percentage instead of absolute value?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop - 1.6
I'm trying to create a Combination where the "**Impact on price**" will be a **Percentage** value (instead of absolute value).

**Problem** is that I don't see how to set this value as a percentage. Take a look at my capture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Combination price is relative to Product price. So, as you know the exactly price of your product, then you must know the exact differencial price for the specific combinations of this product.

What you want to do can't be done with Prestashop default options, but I consider that not neccesary this function so you can do the same with some simple calculations. Anyway, a percent value is the equivalent to a fix value ;)

Good luck.

Comment: "Anyway, a percent value is the equivalent to a fix value" Not exactly. Suppose that one characteristic leads to an increase of 10% and another to an increase of 10%. Altogether, the application of the two characteristics leads to an increase of 10% + 10% + (10% x 10%) = 21% and this should be the correct solution.